# How to give fixed top margin while scrolling the body content to avoid the content display under the transparent fixed Header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have body content with some sections and a header with a transparent background. When I scroll the body content it shows behind the header. I don't have control to change the background of the header. So, I'm looking for a way to keep a top margin for the section in body.

I would prefer to fix this without using Javascript.

I looked for the solutions online but no help. I created an example here to look at it.

```css
/**
 * Layout
 */
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 40em;
    width: 88%;
}

.section {
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 75vh;
    margin: 0;
  scroll-margin-top: 1em;
}

#a { background-color: #0074d9; }
#b { background-color: #2ecc40; }
#c { background-color: #ff851b; }
#d { background-color: #b10dc9; }

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Sticky navigation
 */
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

/**
 * Display lists on a single line.
 * @bugfix Prevent webkit from removing list semantics
 * 1. Add a non-breaking space
 * 2. Make sure it doesn't mess up the DOM flow
 */
.list-inline {
  background: transparent,
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    margin-right: -0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}

.list-inline > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.list-inline > li:before {
    content: "\200B"; /* 1 */
    position: absolute; /* 2 */
}
```

```html
<nav class="sticky">
  <h1>Header</h1>

    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#a">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Section B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#c">Section C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d">Section D</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>

    <article class="section" id="a"><h2>Section A</h2></article>
    <article class="section" id="b"><h2>Section B</h2></article>
    <article class="section" id="c"><h2>Section C</h2></article>
    <article class="section" id="d"><h2>Section D</h2></article>
</main>
```

Any help, please. It would be awsome if I can fix this with just CSS. Feel free to give a fixed height to the header too.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem what we can do is make the body of your page not scrollable and instead make the "main" part of the page scrollable. You can do this by adding `min-height: 100vh;` and `overflow: hidden;` to the body section of your CSS. Next you need to make your nav (.sticky) to have a set height (anything you like) (e.g. `.sticky {height: 100px;}`. Once this is completed you can finally add a CSS section for your "main" tag that should include the following:

```
main {
height: calc(100vh - [HEIGHT OF NAV]);
overflow: auto;
}
```